# Repository singleton data persistence

Tags: java, android, repository-pattern, mvp

I'm using a Repository pattern singleton in conjunction with MVP for an app. I have a sign-up flow where I'm storing data that needs to be used across screens as POJOs in the singleton. Like so:

```
class  SignupRepository {
      private SignupData signupData;

      ......

      void setSignupParam1(String param1) {
            signupData.setParam1(param1);
      }

      SignupData getSignupData() {
            return signupData;
      }
}
```

The issue I'm facing now is that `signupData` gets GC'd if the user puts the app in the background in the middle of the flow. I end up getting a `null` `signupData` object when I'm trying to retrieve a value that I saved in step 1 say when the user is in step 3.  The constraints I'm facing are:

1. I can't get the data that I need from an API. The API call to do the signup is at the end of the flow, I need to hold the data locally till then.
2. The repository isn't aware of the lifecycle of the presenter. If I use a local persistence method like Realm or ObjectBox, I would have to make some sort of persist() method on the repository that would save the POJO to disk. I'm not a fan of this since it leaks the implementation of the repository out to the presenter and makes it dependent on it.
3. I don't want to use SavedInstanceState bundles to restore my data since that would break the MVP pattern completely. My view would provide data to my presenter to save in the repository!

Right now I'm leaning towards option 2, but writing data to disk everytime a setter is called. I'm worried that this might be an expensive call though. Is there any clean way to deal with this?

Comment: so you have multiple activities for the signup process?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque yes, one for each screen

Comment: the best approach in this case would be to replace the activities with fragments and have 1 single signup activity with various fragments collecting the information (in a wizard like way). I've actually implemented this in the app I'm currently working on and the fragments can hold your data until you need them, at the end of the process